# Should I take help of Internet and other programmers or I should do all programming myself?

Tags: programming-practices

I am a developer in a good company. I was given a task by my company to accomplish within a week however I finished the same in 4 days, my boss, the client, and other team members all are happy by my work; even I was! However suddenly I got a thought in my mind: "For my work I took some code from internet and mixed it up with my programming and gave the result faster however, my worry is that I should have done the task all of my own so that I would have a better understanding of it (even which was taken from internet)".

Can anyone tell me if I am ruining my programming career this way (I mean by using others code)?

Comment: Depends on if what you did was illegally garnered and used against its license.

Comment: Rig, Thanks a lot for the comment. However the code which was used was totally licensce free. The question is about my carrier if this kind of behaviour can destroy my programming carrier.

Comment: Cut-and-paste?  Oh, the joy when you have to change it...

Comment: License free sounds to me as if you're not allowed to use the code. If I show you some code I've written, you're not allowed to use it unless I license it to you, or give the rights for the code to you.

Comment: -1: False dichotomy.

Comment: 99.999999999% of us will live our lives without a *single* unique own thought. Every little idea, every thought is practically copy-pasted. So relax and carry on.

Comment: Thnaks. even i think the same way and so i did the same.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Probably* not. Getting parts of solutions online is not that uncommon. If you don't understand what you are copying and pasting from the internet, you will eventually run into trouble. If you take a little bit of time and effort to learn about the code you find and how to adapt it better to your own circumstances, that is fine!

Comment: +1 for "if you don't understand... you will run into trouble."  That's the key to the whole thing.  Some code makes sense once you see it, even though you didn't think of it yourself.  But if it looks like "magic" to you, figure out why it works before committing yourself to using it.

Comment: Yes I do agree with you mason. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.....

Comment: How many upvoters use libraries and compilers downloaded from the internet. What about tools? Are all upvoters here honestly saying that they understand every detail of every piece of code the use. Are you all suggesting that writing 1000's of line yourself is more reliable than using pre-canned source code? Some of you may be good, even exceptionally good, but I very much doubt any of you are that good.

Comment: @mattnz I suppose the droves of nobody who have suggested anything of the sort (except you, of course) gave you this impression? All of the upvoters, myself included, are probably just acutely aware of how valuable **peer collaboration** can be as a teaching tool.

Answer (score 8):

There are two sides to this issue that you need to watch out for. On the one hand, don't reinvent the wheel. On the other hand, avoid licensing traps.

The internet is a great resource for getting code to do things quickly. There are all kinds of useful libraries and other utilities that make life easier. The issue of developer knowledge is certainly important and you do not want to be unable to withstand a code review because your code is replete with someone-else's. As Brian Kergihan once said: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." Using code from people more clever than you are may well (and likely will) result in the inability to debug said code efficiently or effectively.

This leads me into my second point. Almost all code on the internet is licensed. Either explicitly or implicitly by copyright or similar. Certain licenses are very permissive as to what you can do with code, others much less so. The [GNU GPL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) is famous for rendering any code it touches open source by default. Even one function could potentially render you obligated to release your codebase as open source software. Even Stackoverflow and the rest of [Stack Exchange](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) is [licensed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

So by using other people's code willy nilly, you run the risk of both technical and legal [shibolleths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibolleth), the likes of which you may not understand.

Comment: People who complain that debugging is 2x as hard as writing the code should get their act together and read some debugging resources. If debugging is harder than coming up with a good spec and implementation, YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG!!! Debugging is easy, it has always been this way.

Comment: @Coder: If you think that, I can only assume that you've never had to debug a truly difficult problem.  Even with the best of tools, debugging the truly tricky stuff like race conditions or other intermittent errors can leave you pulling your hair out.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: I have, there are debug heaps, step by step walks, automatic debuggers like WinDbg with !locks, and so on. It's a piece of cake compared to coming up with good thread safe algorithm, where you have to prove to yourself that every possible timing condition will still work. Designing safe multi-threaded algorithm is harder than debugging it. It will wither lock on deadlock, corrupt shared data, and then you know it's not protected, or crash with access violation, if some pointer is updated concurrently with actual data without common lock. Easy!

Comment: @Coder Are you saying Brian Kernighan should have got his act together? Wow :P

Comment: @AndresF.: Times have changed, we no longer work with guesswork when working with modern tools. Anyone who complains about debugging nowadays should get their act together. The last part about "always been this way" was an exaggeration though.

Comment: It will take less time to test and debug 10000 lines of code that has already been used elsewhere, than to write it from scratch, test and debug it. If I download a TCP/IP Stack from the internet, I bet I ship my product quicker and more reliable than If I wrote it from scratch. The trick for me is choosing the right download, however, many people here believe they can can whip up a bug free  TCP/IP stack in just a few days because it's really quite a simple task.

Answer (score 3):

Licensing issues aside, I don't think there's a real answer to your question.
If you have a lot of time and think that writing some piece of code by yourself will be useful to you in the future, do it. Otherwise, don't. Or maybe you can copy some piece of code but still take the time to understand it. That might be the best thing to do, or it might not be the best thing to do. It depends on the situation, and you can't really tell for sure until it's over.
It all comes down to making judgments. You can't make the right judgments all the time, but you *can* avoid doing things dogmatically, without looking at the specific situation that you're in... Although, overthinking can be another pitfall.

Comment: Oh yes ! Now I do understand that I can take the code from internet however I should take some time to understand the same(which i usually do). and s I do agree with your point "Although, overthinking can be another pitfall.". Thanks a lot for the answer......

Answer (score 1):

I always try to avoid copy-pasta from Internet, unless the code is exactly what's needed, is an industry standard/best practice, and is free of any licensing issues.

The copy pasta code usually is:

- out of date
- bloated
- adds additional dependencies
- has unknown bugs

It's better to understand the idea. Then write your own solution with code style that matches the project, doesn't add extra dependencies, is simpler, more modern, and better known.

Also, sometimes ideas can be encumbered with patents, so you should be aware of that as well.